# Form: How to put Form-Fields perfectly into table cells?

Tags: hyperref, forms, adobe

[image]

What can I do that the *TextField*s etc. (except for a small "outer sep") fit exactly into the table cells (with their set dimensions)?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx, xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Style
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print, bordercolor=red,
borderstyle={U}, 
bordercolor={red},
backgroundcolor=lightgray!60
}
% Textfields
\def\Name{\mbox{\TextField[name=Name,height=1em, width=0.375\textwidth]{Name:}}%
}
\def\Career{\mbox{\TextField[name=Career,height=1em, width=0.375\textwidth]{Career:}}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{0.5\textwidth} | X |}
\hline
 \Name &  \Career \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \par
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width can be done rather easily by measuring the label. The height is more difficult: the best values depends also a bit on the pdf viewer used and on the exact visual effect you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx, xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Style
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print, bordercolor=red,
borderstyle={U},
bordercolor={red},
backgroundcolor=lightgray!60
}
% Textfields
\newlength\lentmpa

\newcommand\Name{%
 \settowidth\lentmpa{Name: }%
 \mbox{%  
  \TextField[name=Name,
        height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
        width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Name:}}}
\newcommand\Career{\settowidth\lentmpa{Career: }%
         \mbox{%
          \TextField[name=Career,
           height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
           width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Career:}}%
}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 \raisebox{-0.3\normalbaselineskip+2\arrayrulewidth}[0pt][0pt]{#2}%
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{0.5\textwidth} | X |}
\hline
 \Name &  \Career \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \par
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mmmh, very professional. But seems to be problematic if I use a multicolumn...

Comment: I opened a follow-up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467538/form-how-to-put-form-fields-perfectly-into-multicolumn-cells