# Form: How to put Form-Fields perfectly into multicolumn-cells?

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, multicolumn

I have a follow-up question about: [Form: How to put Form-Fields perfectly into table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467497/form-how-to-put-form-fields-perfectly-into-table-cells/467504#467504)

If I use a multicolumn, the calculation method breaks down again.

What do I have to do differently?

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Style
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print, bordercolor=red,
borderstyle={U},
bordercolor={red},
backgroundcolor=lightgray!60
}
% Textfields
\newlength\lentmpa

\newcommand\Name{\settowidth\lentmpa{Name: }%
\mbox{%  
\TextField[name=Name,
height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Name:}}%
}

\newcommand\Career{\settowidth\lentmpa{Career: }%
\mbox{%
\TextField[name=Career,
height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Career:}}%
}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 \raisebox{-0.3\normalbaselineskip+2\arrayrulewidth}[0pt][0pt]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{0.5\textwidth} | X |}
\hline
 \Name &  \Career \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| l |}{\Career}              \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \par
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested here [Wrong column spacing due to multicolumn in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688560/wrong-column-spacing-due-to-multicolumn-in-latex), you could use a fixed-width-multicolumn:

```
\multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep} |}
```

I subtract the width of the rules and the inner padding to fit the linewidth. MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Style
\renewcommand*{\DefaultOptionsofText}{print, bordercolor=red,
borderstyle={U},
bordercolor={red},
backgroundcolor=lightgray!60
}
% Textfields
\newlength\lentmpa

\newcommand\Name{\settowidth\lentmpa{Name: }%
\mbox{%  
\TextField[name=Name,
height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Name:}}%
}

\newcommand\Career{\settowidth\lentmpa{Career: }%
\mbox{%
\TextField[name=Career,
height=\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip-4\arrayrulewidth, 
width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\lentmpa]{Career:}}%
}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 \raisebox{-0.3\normalbaselineskip+2\arrayrulewidth}[0pt][0pt]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{0.5\textwidth} | X |}
\hline
 \Name &  \Career \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\arrayrulewidth-2\tabcolsep} |}{\Career}              \\ \hline
\end{tabularx} \par
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE result]