# How to get the row height and column width within a tabular?

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, size, height

Do you know how I can specify the size of a cell in points (pt) within a tabular, that is the row height and the column witdh? In text mode there are commands like `\textwidth` or `\baselineskip` but this does not work within a `tabular` environment. I do not want to adjust these parameters, I only want to know their values.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
  Row Height:   & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getRowHeight" \\
  Column Width: & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getColWidth"
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: they are not in general known to the macro layer you need to do a two pass system that either boxes and measures the entries by hand not relying on the table mechanism to give the size, or record coordinates in the aux file (`\pdfsavepos` or a wrapper such as `\tikzmark`) and then pick them up on the next run of latex.

Answer (score 5):

In the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have PGF/Tikz nodes which are created under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use those nodes to compute the dimensions of the current cell and use Tikz back again to put the result in the cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pantigny_SizeOfCell:nn 
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path let \p1 = (#1-|#2) ,
              \p2 = (\int_eval:n{#1+1}-|\int_eval:n{#2+1}) 
          in node at (#1-#2) 
             { \dim_eval:n { \x2 - \x1 } $\times$ \dim_eval:n{\y1-\y2} } ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \SizeOfCell {}
  {
    \NotEmpty
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_after_tl
      { \__pantigny_SizeOfCell:nn { \arabic { iRow } } { \arabic { jCol } } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
AAAA & AAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAA & BB \\
BB & \SizeOfCell  & CCC \\
CC & BBBBB  & DD
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1. You may want to point out explicitly that `12.4pt` is the sum of `\baselineskip` and `\arrayrulewidth` (which is 0.4pt by default). Sure enough, if one were to run `\fontsize{10}{20}\selectfont` and `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2.5pt}`, the cell height would come to `22.5pt`.

Comment: @Mico: You are right.

Comment: Maybe it would be nice, if `NiceTabular` (and `NiceMatrix`) elements do offer some functions to determine these values? :D

Answer (score 3):

`tabstackengine` shares some of the features that are available through `tabular`.  One additional thing it does is provide `\TABwd{}` to provide column width of the most recently created TABstack.  Likewise, `\TABht{}` and `\TABdp{}` can be used for row heights/depths.

As seen in the MWE, these quantities are available inside the TABstack and afterwards, as well.

These quantities provide the height & width of the row/column not accounting for border.  In order to account for the additional border of the stack, there is `\tabular@gap` separation between inner columns (but not around the outer edges), and (in the case of a short stack such as this, `\Sstackgap` space between rows.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl}
  Row Height:    & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getRowHeight" \\
  Columdn Width: & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getColWidth"
\end{tabular}

\the\tabcolsep

\setstacktabulargap{12pt}% COMPARABLE TO 2\tabcolsep
\tabularShortstack{rl}{
  Row Height:    & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getRowHeight" \\
  Columdn Width: & "\textbackslash{}the \textbackslash{}getColWidth"\\
  \rule{\TABwd{1}}{\dimexpr\TABht{2}+\TABdp{1}}& 
  \rule{\TABwd{2}}{\dimexpr\TABht{2}+\TABdp{1}}
}

\bigskip
Column widths:
\TABwd{1}, \TABwd{2}

\medskip
Row heights/depths:
\TABht{1}/\TABdp{1}, \TABht{2}/\TABdp{2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to point out that 8.2125pt+2.7375pt=10.95pt. (Unlike the "basic" LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book`, which use `10pt` as the default font size, the KOMA-Script classes use 10.95pt as the default font size. 10.95 is the *geometric* average of 10 and 12. Don't ask...) As such, your method for determining the cell height may not be factoring in (a) the value of `\baselineskip` and (b) the width parameter `\arrayrulewidth`.

Comment: @Mico If one wants `\baselineskip` to be accounted for, one must use Longstacks instead of Shortstacks.  As to `\arrayrulewidth`, tabstacks do not intrinsically support `\hline`s.  The `TABcline` package option provides something akin to `\cline`, except that the lines are actually created as their own row in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

An approach demonstrating the usage of `zsavepos`.

Alternative (use `\vadjust` so you don't need to put the `\noalign` around the table rows):

- [Crossing out multirow/multicolumn cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365620/250119)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156172/250119

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \noalign{\zsaveposy{celltop}}
  \textcolor{red}{\rule[-50pt]{0.25pt}{100pt}} & 456 &  \zsaveposx{cellleft} \hfill 789 \hfill \zsaveposx{cellright}  \\
  \noalign{\zsaveposy{cellbottom}}
  \hline
  123 & 456 & \textcolor{blue}{\rule{99pt}{0.25pt}} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

height of cell: \the\dimexpr \zposy{celltop}sp-\zposy{cellbottom}sp \relax

width of cell: \the\dimexpr \zposx{cellright}sp-\zposx{cellleft}sp \relax

\end{document}
```

Output image:

[image: output image]